# Incompatible pointer type fscanf [C]

Tags: c

```
linkedList *createFreqTable(char *file) {
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int fCount = 0;
    int sizeLimit = 128;
    struct tnode *nodes = malloc(128 * sizeof(struct tnode));
    char *character;

    /* Open a file stream */
    FILE *stream;
    /* Reads in the file */
    stream = fopen(file, "r");
    /* Scan the file until EOF */
    while (fscanf(file, "%c", &character) != EOF) {
        ...
```

Getting a warning message saying `passing argument 1 of 'fscanf' from incompatible pointer type.` Any clue on what is wrong with the code?

Comment: You are passing an incompatible pointer type

Comment: And you did not find the documentation of `fread`? Read how to use files in a C book. That is very basic knowledge.

Comment: `fscanf(file, "%c", &character)` --> `fscanf(stream, "%c", &character)`. Plus `char* character;` --> `char character;`

Comment: @olaf, That is why this site was put here in the first place, right? It's really easy to read over some of this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%c` conversion specifier expects an argument of type `char *`.  You've declared the variable `character` to have type `char *`.  Thus, the *expression* `&character` in the `scanf` call has type `char **`.

Declare `character` as a regular `char`, not a `char *`:

```
char character;
...
while(fscanf(stream, "%c", &character) == 1) {
```

Note that you *don't* want to keep `character` as a pointer and just drop the `&` in the `scanf` call, because `character` isn't pointing anywhere meaningful at this point.

**Edit**

chqrlie pointed out a few other errors that I missed the first time around - you should be passing `stream` instead of `file` as the first argument to `fscanf`, and you should compare the result to `1` instead of `EOF` (since you're scanning for a single item).

Comment: Also fix the incorrect argument `file`, should be `stream`, and the OP should be testing `== 1` instead of `!= EOF`.  These are equivalent in this specific example, but `!= EOF` would be incorrect for any other format.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the compiler complains about the type mismatch between `char *file` and `FILE *stream` expected as first argument for `fscanf`.  The other error you spotted was probably not diagnosed by the compiler because of insufficient warning level... and not all compilers analyze `scanf` and `printf` format strings.

Comment: @chqrlie: Done.  Embarrased that I didn't catch those myself.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains because you are passing `file` instead of `stream` to `fscanf`.  You should also pass the address of a `char` for format `%c`, not the address of a `char*`.  Change the definition of `character` to `char character;`.

For better performance, it would be more efficient to use `fgetc()` instead of `fscanf()` to read the file one byte at a time.

You would then define `character` as an `int`:

```
linkedList *createFreqTable(char *file) {
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int fCount = 0;
    int sizeLimit = 128;
    struct tnode *nodes = malloc(128 * sizeof(struct tnode));
    int character;

    FILE *stream = fopen(file, "r");
    if (stream == NULL) {
        /* handle this error */
        ...
        return NULL;
    }
    /* Scan the file until EOF */
    while ((character = fgetc(stream)) != EOF) {
        ...
```